# How can I convert a list of dictionaries into a list of rows moving column-by-column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a list of dictionaries into a list of rows that contain the columns for those rows. I also want the order to start at column 1 and move down to the bottom of the column, then start on the next column, etc., until the list has been completed.

I also know that my `max_items_per_column = 25`

Let's say I have a list like this `my_list = [1,2,3,...89,90]` but with simple dictionaries like below:

```
my_list = [dict1, dict2, ... dict90]
```

And I want to convert it to look like this:

```
 1  26  51   76
 2  27  52   77
 3  28  53   78
 4  29  54   79
 5  30  55   80
 6  31  56   81
 7  32  57   82
 8  33  58   83
 9  34  59   84
10  35  60   85
11  36  61   86
12  37  62   87
13  38  63   88
14  39  64   89
15  40  65   90
16  41  66   
17  42  67   
18  43  68   
19  44  69   
20  45  70   
21  46  71   
22  47  72   
23  48  73   
24  49  74   
25  50  75
```

So the converted list could be declared like this:

```
converted_list = [
    [dict1, dict26, dict51, dict76],
    [dict2, dict27, dict52, dict77],
    [dict3, dict28, dict53, dict78],
    .
    .
    .
    [dict25, dict50, dict75,None]
]
```

I'm not sure how to do this, and I'm also not sure if this would be best done using Pandas or not.

Comment: Where do the dicts come from? Is there no other way of organizing the data like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it as a dataframe in your final format, you can do it like this:

```
my_list = [i for i in range(1, 91)] # setting up an example
next_list = [my_list[x:x+25] for x in range(0, len(my_list), 25)] # groups into a list of lists of len 25 each
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(next_list).T
```

df looks like:

```
>>> df
       0     1     2     3
0    1.0  26.0  51.0  76.0
1    2.0  27.0  52.0  77.0
2    3.0  28.0  53.0  78.0
3    4.0  29.0  54.0  79.0
4    5.0  30.0  55.0  80.0
5    6.0  31.0  56.0  81.0
6    7.0  32.0  57.0  82.0
7    8.0  33.0  58.0  83.0
8    9.0  34.0  59.0  84.0
9   10.0  35.0  60.0  85.0
10  11.0  36.0  61.0  86.0
11  12.0  37.0  62.0  87.0
12  13.0  38.0  63.0  88.0
13  14.0  39.0  64.0  89.0
14  15.0  40.0  65.0  90.0
15  16.0  41.0  66.0   NaN
16  17.0  42.0  67.0   NaN
17  18.0  43.0  68.0   NaN
18  19.0  44.0  69.0   NaN
19  20.0  45.0  70.0   NaN
20  21.0  46.0  71.0   NaN
21  22.0  47.0  72.0   NaN
22  23.0  48.0  73.0   NaN
23  24.0  49.0  74.0   NaN
24  25.0  50.0  75.0   NaN
```

If you want to convert that back to a list of lists you can do something like this:

```
converted_list = []
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    my_list = [rows[0], rows[1], rows[2], rows[3]]
    converted_list.append(my_list)
```

converted_list:

```
[[1.0, 26.0, 51.0, 76.0], [2.0, 27.0, 52.0, 77.0], [3.0, 28.0, 53.0, 78.0], [4.0, 29.0, 54.0, 79.0], [5.0, 30.0, 55.0, 80.0], [6.0, 31.0, 56.0, 81.0], [7.0, 32.0, 57.0, 82.0], [8.0, 33.0, 58.0, 83.0], [9.0, 34.0, 59.0, 84.0], [10.0, 35.0, 60.0, 85.0], [11.0, 36.0, 61.0, 86.0], [12.0, 37.0, 62.0, 87.0], [13.0, 38.0, 63.0, 88.0], [14.0, 39.0, 64.0, 89.0], [15.0, 40.0, 65.0, 90.0], [16.0, 41.0, 66.0, nan], [17.0, 42.0, 67.0, nan], [18.0, 43.0, 68.0, nan], [19.0, 44.0, 69.0, nan], [20.0, 45.0, 70.0, nan], [21.0, 46.0, 71.0, nan], [22.0, 47.0, 72.0, nan], [23.0, 48.0, 73.0, nan], [24.0, 49.0, 74.0, nan], [25.0, 50.0, 75.0, nan]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. The only issue I ran into was a `KeyError` at this line `my_list = [rows[0], rows[1], rows[2], rows[3]]`. Here is what I ended up doing to get around it https://repl.it/@chadsaunders/DazzlingSnivelingTransformation

Comment: That's a nice tool you posted! Strange to see that a difference is required to make it run, this works for me. Glad it works!